# adding views to UINavigationController using the interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

There's a good chance I missed something major here but I'll ask anyway.
In my storyboard app I've sub classed `UINavigationController` to my needs. (using a simple .h & .m files)
I've added a custom back button, a menu button and some other stuff that will be visible in the Navigation bar across my app.

My question is, how can I add objects (`UIView` , `UIButton` etc') to my sub classed `UINavigationController` using the **interface builder**? ( So far I've added everything I wanted through code)

Obviously I can't drag views to the `UINavigationController`. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

It is not possible to add subviews to a `UINavigationController`'s view in Interface Builder.  If you want to do that, you must do it in code.

#### ORIGINAL

You don't add subviews to the `UINavigationController`'s view.  You create a separate view controller and connect the navigation controller to the new view controller using the “root view controller” relationship segue.  Then you add your views (buttons, etc.) to the root view controller's view.  Here's an example:

[image: storyboard with navigation controller and root view controller]
(Click for full size.)

The left view controller is the navigation controller.  The right navigation controller is the root view controller.  They are connected by the “root view controller” relationship (segue).

You cannot add buttons or any other views to the left view controller's scene.  You can only add them to the right view controller's scene.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I was totally misunderstood. I've edited my question.. I've already added views to the Navigation Controller Subclass with code ( a custom back button, a menu that will always be visible on all views of the app etc') I was wondering if I can do the same with the interface builder instead of writing the code in my Navigation Controller subclass .m file

Comment: Ah.  Well, the answer is no.  Interface Builder will not let you add subviews directly to a navigation controller's view.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the comment above so I can accept. Thanks